# Swap div items using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are two list items in a div and one swap button. On click of swap i have to change the order of items. I am able to achieve it using below `swap` function.

```js
var ints = [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ],
    chars = [ "A", "B", "C", "D"],
    list1 = document.getElementById("list1"),
    list2 = document.getElementById("list2"),
    toggle = 0;

setList(list1, ints);
setList(list2, chars);

function setList(element, data) {
  for (var i in data) {  
    var elem = document.createElement("li");
    elem.innerText = data[i];
    element.appendChild(elem);
  }
}

function swap() {
  list1.innerHTML = "";
  list2.innerHTML = "";
  if(toggle==0) {
    setList(list1, chars);
    setList(list2, ints);
    toggle=1;
  } else {
    setList(list1, ints);
    setList(list2, chars);
    toggle=0;
  }  
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<ul id="list1"></ul>
<ul id="list2"></ul>
</div>

<button id="btn" onclick="swap()">Swap</button>
```

I am wondering if this functionality can be achieved using CSS.
Code can be tested on codepen as well https://codepen.io/imjaydeep/pen/EBvaxG?editors=1111

Comment: you can simply do this with order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: @TemaniAfif i have saved the pen using css order property but its not working, not sure if i have done it correctly.

Comment: You specified the same `order: 1` for both elements, that does not change anything - elements are sorted by the order value first, and then by their natural order in the DOM second. Make that `#list2 { order: 0; }` instead, and you will see the alphabetically “indexed” list show first.

Comment: @TemaniAfif gotcha.. was not removing the classes properly, kept order:1 for both the lists and toggled it.. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved using CSS order property.

```js
var ints = [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ],
    chars = [ "A", "B", "C", "D"],
    list1 = document.getElementById("list1"),
    list2 = document.getElementById("list2"),
    toggle = 0;

setList(list1, ints);
setList(list2, chars);

function setList(element, data) {
  for (var i in data) {  
    var elem = document.createElement("li");
    elem.innerText = data[i];
    element.appendChild(elem);
  }
}

function swap() {
  if (toggle==0) {
    list1.classList.remove('list1');
    list2.classList.add('list2');
    toggle=1;
  } else {
    list2.classList.remove('list2');
    list1.classList.add('list1');
    toggle=0;
  }  
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px !important;
}

.list1 {
  order: 1;
}

.list2 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<ul id="list1"></ul>
<ul id="list2"></ul>
</div>

<button id="btn" onclick="swap()">Swap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Replace the button with a checkbox and use that to toggle swap, in this case, reversing the row order of the container div

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#swap:checked + div {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
 <label>Swap</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="swap" />
  <div>
    <ul id="list1">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```